# Installation of ELMAH in MVC Project

Tags: elmah.mvc

When installing ELMAH via Visual Studio 2012 Nuget Manager, i'm getting a window where i have to log on(see screenshot).
I registered myself on nuget.org, but using that account, i still can't install ELMAH and still get that logon window.
Some help with will be great!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is very strange, I personally never saw anything like that. Can you elaborate, what actually are you doing?

To access nuget packages you don't need to have nuget account. You can install, either by right click on target project and select corresponding menu item or, in Power Shell window

```
Install-Package Elmah.Mvc
```

Comment: Im opening the 'Package Manager Console' and type: Install-Package Elmah.Mvc, then i get that window. Clicking on cancel on the window, gives me this error:Install-Package : An error occurred while loading packages from'https://nuget.org/api/v2/': The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Elmah.Mvc
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: 1. make sure your VS uses laters NuGet 2. make sure nuget.org api is not blocked by your firewall;